# Missing functions in Router API documentation

Tags: ember.js

I was looking at the source code for Ember.Router and I noticed that the map function is not documented. It's described in the Guides but not in the API. I kind of expected such an important function to have an entry in the API docs. Should I open a bug report for this? I'm not sure I know enough about Ember to submit something myself. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely submit a PR for it.  Honestly most people look at the tutorials and use SO before they look into the API, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be properly documented.  I'd just steal from the tutorials and submit a PR.